# Is it the CDM's foul if they cleanly kick the ball away from the attaker before the shot but then get kicked instead by the attacker in the process?

Tags: football, officiating

Basically, I was in a 8 vs 8 football game the other day and the striker was getting ready to line up for a shot.

However, the CDM managed to run from the back right side of the striker and nick/kick the ball away from the striker (by sticking a leg from the side and without slide tackling) in the last second before they were able to shoot. Instead the striker then kicked the CDMs back calf.

The CDM was able to continue to run for the ball for half a second but since they got kicked in the calf quite hard, they fell to the ground (it was a small knock).

The CDM claimed it was the defending teams foul since they got to the ball first, cleanly and without fouling or touching the ST.

The ST claimed that it was actually the attacking teams foul because they had possession of the ball and the defender came from behind and obstructed the shot.

Both points were valid and we couldn't agree, so the defending team decided to give the ball back to the attacking teams goalie and restart the play from the back.

So I was wondering, who should get the foul in this instance... the CDM or the ST? Or are both points valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Situations like this one should always be backed with visual evidence, otherwise it's hard to tell.

Based on what you've provided the defending player (CDM) should have been awarded a free-kick. The striker was simply too late or too slow. Things like that happen all the time. They're not reckless or dangerous, but they're a foul.

The STs claim would have been ok, if the CDM stuck their leg out without touching the ball. (Again, no visual evidence, no "real" answer possible.)

Comment: Not sure I agree fully, though it's certainly possible that this would be the case, it seems to me there's very possibly arguments for fouls to be given to either or neither player.  What it sounds like to me is the defender effectively put their foot in between the striker's foot and the ball - not that they clearly got the ball away first *then* were kicked.  Coming from behind makes a difference, no?  (In the physics, more so than the legalities otherwise).

Comment: @Joe coming from behind isn't illegal per se. And playing the ball from behind without sliding into it is a good play. ("*However, the CDM managed to run from the back right side of the striker and nick/kick the ball away from the striker*" sound to me like they managed to play the ball and not just block it off) A sliding tackle from behind would be reckless and is often whistled off depending on the situation. But I said it twice in my post. You need to see it to be absolutely sure.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs joe and dly. As @dly mentioned, without visual evidence making the decision is quite tough. We were there, experienced it, saw it and still couldn't agree on a clear cut decision. What I would say is that the CDM definitely got to the ball first and if the CDM got away before the ST kicked the CDM then we would have continued play and recognised that it was a clean tackle. Even the ST recognised they weren't touched during the challenge but they're  problem was that the CDM came from behind and got in the way of the shot.